# Convert string Date into Date object in android

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone, utc

I have date string "`2016-02-13T05:30:00+05:30`". I want to convert this into Date object in local timezone.

Example if Mobile device timezone is US/CANADA timezone then this string date's output will be "`2016-02-12T04:00:00-13:30`" in string.

Comment: Just google it you will find atleast 20-25 links for this.

Comment: There are no time zones that are `-13:30`.

Comment: yes it getting convert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ", Locale.US);      
Log.e("StackOverflowPost", "formatted string : " + sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
```

and take a look at the [android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) official web site